# Redirect back to Default.aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, postback, webmethod

I have a default.aspx (c#) page which has a simple Post AJAX call to a `WebMethod` that returns a JSON object, so that I can then populate a DataTable. All worked fine until I introduced a login page. Now, when a user is redirected to the Default page, after logging in, the Post never appears in FireBug.

This is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Default.aspx/GetValueDateSummary',
            contentType: 'json',
            data: {},
            sucess: function (response) {
                renderTable(response.d);
            },
            error: function (errMsg) {
                $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);
            }
        });
    });
```

with the code behind being:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static List<ValueDateSummary> GetValueDateSummary()
{
    some code in here.....

   return drList;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Default.aspx/GetValueDateSummary',
                contentType: 'json',
                data: {},
                sucess: function (response) {
                    renderTable(response.d);
                },
                error: function (errMsg) {
                    $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);
                }
            });
        });

Comment: Does firebug show any JS errors? If you `console.log` immediately before the ajax call does it show up?

Comment: No firebug errors Matt - in the NET tab there are only POSTS, no sign of my GET

Comment: How about injecting a `console.log`, or breakpointing the `$.ajax` call in Firebug? Are you sure that that line is being reached?

Comment: You say "no sign of my GET", but the above code is a POST. Have you checked it?

Comment: sorry Vinny, i meant post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i sorted it.

here is the complate Ajax call, seems i was missing the proper contentType and dataType

```
               $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'Default.aspx/GetValueDateSummary',
               contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response) {
                   console.log(response);
                   alert(response.d);
                   renderTable(response.d);
               },
               error: function (errMsg) {
                   $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sucess: function (response) {
```

should be

```
success: function (response) {
```

Comment: That would explain why `renderTable` was never being called, but would not explain why the request was never being made.

Comment: You've also got two closings for the ajax function. });

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. I cannot really help much more apart from pointing out mistakes on the code you posted. Have you got a fiddle or more code we can see?

Comment: Hi Matt, well spotted on the typo - made no difference though, as you thought

Comment: It was Vinny that spotted the typo. I'm going to go ahead and assume that the extra closing that Vinny also spotted is just a result of copy & pasting one line too many, because otherwise that would be a syntax error that should show up in Firebug.

Comment: just running console.log now.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
http://localhost:65241/SASMI_Web/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Line 3

Comment: JSON.parse would be called on the receipt of a response to the ajax request. See Vinny's comment to the question, wherein he points out you're asking for your ajax to be a POST but only looking for GETs in your net tab. I think the request is being sent, not sure how you're getting an apparently malformed response back though, perhaps .NET is erroring out because it was told to expect a GET.

Comment: Ok, making some progress. there seems to be a problem with the jquery-1.9.1.js file. Visual studio breaks on this line

each: function(obj, callback, args)

only the callback param has anything, the rest are undefined - and it is length = obj.length which is causing the POST from working.

Comment: Sounds like the real error is somewhere up the call stack from there.

Comment: indeed, this was all working fine until i introduced a login page.

Comment: I meant the javascript execution stack at the moment the exception is thrown. Something is calling `jQuery.each()` with bad parameters. A quick scan of the ajax code in jQuery doesn't offer any obvious clues as to what that might be - `each` isn't called directly by either `jQuery.ajax` or the default response handler.

Comment: each: function( obj, callback, args ) {

beginning to think that this isn't anything to do with my post at all. I've disabled authentication access, and this is still being thrown

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ScriptManager object?  If so, I believe that you need to enable page methods for it to work.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: EnablePageMethods just causes the generation of a JavaScript proxy for calling the page methods. If you're using jQuery to make the request, you don't need that JavaScript, and therefore probably don't want the wasted bytes & client parse time.

Comment: yeah, not using the scriptManager